# Have different colors for different hyperlinks within an Android Textview

Tags: android, colors, hyperlink, textview

I know that i can change the color of hyperlinks at the level of a textview by setting:

```
yourText.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Within a Textview I can have multiple hyperlinks in my app. I would like to define a different color for each hyperlink-text. Using 
`<font color ...>`does not work unfortunately.
 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you set hyperlinks to the TextView? Linkify or Html.fromHtml()

Comment: You will need to use spannableString with touchableSpan

Comment: @MeliX: I use Html.fromHtml()

Comment: @karandeep singh: could you please provide details?

Answer (score 1):

```
 String myString = "I accept the Terms of Use, Privacy Policy and I agree";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(myString);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new TouchableSpan(normalColor, touchColor, pressedColor) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            //perform your action to open webview or whatever
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan2 = new TouchableSpan(normalColor, touchColor, pressedColor) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            //perform your action to open webview or whatever
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 13, 25, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan2, 26, 41, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.text = ss;
    textView.movementMethod =new LinkTouchMovementMethod();
```

**Explanation**

```
 ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 13, 25, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This will make

> Terms of Use

clickable. Similarly, the second span will make

> privacy policy

clickable in my sample string. You can use the `normal color`,`touchColor` and `pressedColor` according to your needs.

**TouchableSpan.java**

```
public abstract class TouchableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
private boolean mIsPressed;
private int mPressedBackgroundColor;
private int mNormalTextColor;
private int mPressedTextColor;

public TouchableSpan(int normalTextColor, int pressedTextColor, int pressedBackgroundColor) {
    mNormalTextColor = normalTextColor;
    mPressedTextColor = pressedTextColor;
    mPressedBackgroundColor = 0xffeeeeee;
}

public void setPressed(boolean isSelected) {
    mIsPressed = isSelected;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setColor(mIsPressed ? mPressedTextColor : mNormalTextColor);
    ds.bgColor = mIsPressed ? mPressedBackgroundColor : Color.TRANSPARENT;
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
}
}
```

**LinkTouchMovementMethod.java**

```
public class LinkTouchMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
private TouchableSpan mPressedSpan;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView textView, Spannable spannable, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mPressedSpan = getPressedSpan(textView, spannable, event);
        if (mPressedSpan != null) {
            mPressedSpan.setPressed(true);
            Selection.setSelection(spannable, spannable.getSpanStart(mPressedSpan),
                    spannable.getSpanEnd(mPressedSpan));
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        TouchableSpan touchedSpan = getPressedSpan(textView, spannable, event);
        if (mPressedSpan != null && touchedSpan != mPressedSpan) {
            mPressedSpan.setPressed(false);
            mPressedSpan = null;
            Selection.removeSelection(spannable);
        }
    } else {
        if (mPressedSpan != null) {
            mPressedSpan.setPressed(false);
            super.onTouchEvent(textView, spannable, event);
        }
        mPressedSpan = null;
        Selection.removeSelection(spannable);
    }
    return true;
}

private TouchableSpan getPressedSpan(TextView textView, Spannable spannable, MotionEvent
        event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    x -= textView.getTotalPaddingLeft();
    y -= textView.getTotalPaddingTop();

    x += textView.getScrollX();
    y += textView.getScrollY();

    Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
    int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
    int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

    TouchableSpan[] link = spannable.getSpans(off, off, TouchableSpan.class);
    TouchableSpan touchedSpan = null;
    if (link.length > 0) {
        touchedSpan = link[0];
    }
    return touchedSpan;
}

 }
```

Comment: thanks Karandeep Singh! I am using html-tags (like bold, italic, colors, but also "a href") within my string. Looking at your solution I would have to convert the "a href"-links to setspan calls. what about other html tags?

Comment: This approach cannot be used for muti language apps (almost all prod apps) because you cannot guess the start/end for your hyperlink strings